# MySQL lock tables ignored

Tags: mysql, myisam

I've encoutered strange problem with MySQL table locks with MyISAM engine.

Let's say I have this type of code:

```
LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE;
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE val1 FROM t1 WHERE something; // val1 = old
// some conditions on val1 and logic
UPDATE t1 SET val1 = new WHERE something;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

As far as I know, this should prevent any concurrent updates. But it does not. Sometimes it just ignores lock and "old" is read in val1 after another thread changed it to "new". I even use SQL_NO_CACHE to prevent retrieve old data by mistake.

Why is that? How can I prevent update race for sure?

Thanks.

*MySQL 5.5.28, MyISAM, PHP 5.2, mysql_ extension (obsolete, but on legacy project)*

**Edit:**

OK, it should not happen in pure SQL, so there is the PHP code:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(...);

...

mysql_query("LOCK TABLES t1, t2 WRITE"); //t2 also used
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT last_user, ... FROM t1 WHERE id = XXX"));

if($result["last_user"] != $session_user) { //is last activity from another than current user?
 DoStuffWithUser(...); //custom function which uses t2 table
 mysql_query("UPDATE t1 SET last_user = ".$session_user." WHERE id = XXX");
}

mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
...
?>
```

Result is, that DoStuffWithUser() is called more than once for current user.

No special app, drivers, frameworks. Just built-in PHP functions.

It appears, that problem is mainly (I can't be sure if exclusively) when ONE user performs action multiple times - doubleclick, some network glitch, whatever.

Comment: `and "old" is read in val1 after another thread changed it to "new"` what is the application making these updates? Prehaps the driver is what is doing the caching?

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, and while bugs can happen, this is a very old, often used and tested feature, so it seems more likely that you did something wrong in your code or that it's an external effect (e.g. auto reconnect? connection pooling?). To check what's going on I'd try to log to a log table (with autoincrement) right after the lock, right after val1 and right before and after releasing the lock, and check if there is some unexpected order.

Comment: I've added php code also, to be clear...

Comment: @Solarflare log table done and tested (by me, multiclick). In log table I can see I made two more connections after first LOCK, which were able to read and update locked tables - so log order is like lock1, lock2, select1, select2, update1, update2, dostuff1, lock3, dostuff2, unlock1, select3, unlock2, unlock3. So third connection did not perform action, but still interfierd with other locks...

Comment: `Lock1, lock2` should already not be possible, session 2 should wait right there before it can get the lock. Can you include `connection_id()` (and the value for val1) in your logs, to exclude that you are either reconnecting or reusing the same connection for what you assume are different sessions. Also, can you check that your table is not a temporary table? (It doesn't seem to make sense from context, but just to be sure). I also assume you are not using a cluster/loadbalancing(replication) setup or something like that.

Comment: @Solarflare No temporary table, no replication, nothing like that. Connections were different, no shared session - checked twice - with random string in php session and connection_id() in mysql too. lock1, select1... connection_id() let's say 1234, lock2, select2... different connection_id() 1235. _should already not be possible_ is something I read in manual and on other sites (and books and everywhere) for 3 days :)

Comment: Well, with "should" I of course meant "is". The puzzle is figuring out what you are doing wrong. My next (and possibly only left) guess is that the user doesn't have the lock privilege, and you don't notice it since you do not check the result of `mysql_query` (thanks btw for adding the php code). So check the return value and `echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: Geez, you are also using the deprecated `mysql_*` interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this is my song today https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48rz8udZBmQ

Many thaks to @Solarflare for pushing me right way.

*OK, there is mistake somewhere, let's find it. First line, simple lock query, nothing to check, it's so obvious...* Oh, wait...

```
LOCK TABLES t1 **WRITE**, t2 WRITE
```

Every table has to have lock type set :)